# Positioning of jQuery div

Tags: jquery, css

So i have link to shows a hidden div, that has this following CSS applied to it:

```
.ind-infoNode {
    display:none;
    background:url(/_images/employer-toggle-bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat; 
    height:250px; 
    width:645px;
    padding:20px 35px 30px 20px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
}
```

When the div is displayed it shows up essentially right in the middle of the screen where the link is located on the page, that is in FireFox and Chrome...HOWEVER

In IE, it shows up at the very bottom of the page, under all of the content on the page..

What can i do to resolve this?

Here is the js used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[id^=ind-info-lnk]").live("click", function () { 
        var num = this.id.split(/-(?:lnk)?/).pop(); 
        $('#ind-info-'+num).show(); 
        return false; 
    });  

    $(function() { 
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {   
            if (e.which == 27) {  
                $('.ind-infoNode').hide();  
            }  
        });  
        $('a.close').click(function() {   
            $('.ind-infoNode').hide();  
            return false;   
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What jQuery version are you running?

Comment: Which version of IE and do you have a test page?  With a simple example I'm not seeing much of a difference in IE8 and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `position: absolute` you have to make sure, that the parent element also has a css-property for `position`, no matter which value it has. May be this solves your problem in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that since you are positioning it absolute, `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and/or `right` needs to defined in your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the div to the top of your body element?